# List sorting troubles

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a list of programmers:

```
programmers.Add(new Programmer("Jake", 1.9, 2000));
programmers.Add(new Programmer("Richard", 1.0, 1300));
```

and I need to create a new list of sorted programmers by this 
`value => 2000 / 1.9`.(upward)

I can't figure out how to divide `int` by `double` and sort the `programmers` by this result. Can you please help me how to do so?

So far I've tried:

```
var ProgrammersSorted = programmers.OrderBy((x,y) => x.DailyWage / y.Speed).ToList();
```

Programmer class:

```
public class Programmer
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public double Speed { get; private set; }
    public int DailyWage { get; private set; }

    public Project Project { get; private set; }

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return Project?.Name ?? "No project assigned";
        }
    }

    public Programmer(string name, double speed, int dailyWage)
    {
        Name = name;
        Speed = speed;
        DailyWage = dailyWage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you did.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please show what you have tried so far.  Please show us the code where you are building this list and how you are currently attempting to perform this division and to sort the list.

Comment: Please do not add code in comments, edit your question to include this information. You should also show us the `Programmer` class since you are referencing properties from it.

Comment: Kind of: `programmers.OrderBy(p => (decimal)(p.DailyWage/y.Speed))` ?

Comment: Read about the OrderBy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close. Try this out:

```
var programmersSorted = programmers.OrderBy(x => x.DailyWage / x.Speed).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code, I think this will solve your issue.

```
        var programmers = new List<Programmer>
        {
         new Programmer("SS",12.3,2345),
         new Programmer("ADE",1.21,22345),
         new Programmer("AR",12.2,23445),
         new Programmer("NK",12.5,23455)
        };

        var progrmrs = programmers.OrderBy(t => t.DailyWage / t.Speed).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Name\t Speed\t DailyWage");
        foreach (var prgrm in progrmrs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t {1}\t {2}", prgrm.Name, prgrm.Speed, prgrm.DailyWage);
        }
```